.NET Core Mfa with refresh token
I need to implement multi-factor authentication (MFA)
I've successfully set up basic authentication with AWS Cognito using the AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider package. However, I'm struggling to handle MFA challenges and automatically refresh the access token when it expires.
I'm looking for a clean and efficient way to handle MFA prompts and refresh tokens within my .NET Core application, ensuring a seamless user experience.

Doesn't the AWS Cognito client library handle challenges and refreshes for you? If not, other OAuth2/OIDC libraries (assuming this is OAuth2 or OIDC, right?) can - such as Duende's IdentityModel

You can use the AWS  Cognito client library to handle challenges, Cognito provides different flow types which you can use, also there's a lambda hook you can use to send the MFA token with your implementation

I’ve actually found a way around it, it’s more similar to what you suggested.
